# Move permission set assignment in different tier using ANT

Tags: permissions, profile, permission-sets, user-profile, custom-permission

I have created custom permission and added it to newly created permission set and assigned users to that permission set. I was able to

> move Permission set and Custom Permission file from DEV to Staging

tier using ANT, **but user assignment to those permission set is not reflected in Staging**. How can I move Permission Set assignments using metadata API? How can I locate that file? Do I have to change anything in manifest/Package.xml to enable some folder that I might not be seeing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to move those assignments via metadata deployments. You can assign permission sets via PermissionSetAssignment records, which can be loaded as regular Data Loader files, or you can use Salesforce DX to assign those users.